# How to deduce the type of lambda's return value.?

Tags: c++, c++11

As per the documatation([What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)),
**The return type of the lambda could be deduced in this code.**
**I could not get the idea how it could be done?**

```
    void func4(std::vector<double>& v) 
    {
      std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(),
                     [](double d) { return d < 0.00001 ? 0 : d; }
                     );
    }
```

**But,it cannot be deduced in this example, why?**

```
 void func4(std::vector<double>& v) {
        std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(),
            [](double d) {
                if (d < 0.0001) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return d;
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: In the first, the working of the `?:` operator is specified so the `0` (type `int`) will be promoted, according to rules of promotion of numeric types, to `double` (the type of `d`), so that is the deduced return type. In the second case, there are two distinct `return` statements, one returning `int` and the other `double`.  However, in this case, there is no requirement that rules of promotion of numeric types be followed between distinct `return` statements, giving the compiler ambiguity about whether the return type is `int` or `double`, so it cannot deduce the return type.

Comment: Please add the error message to the question.

Comment: @Robert Andrzejuk What error message?Complie error?

Comment: Are you satisfied with the answer below? If so, consider pressing the green tick next to it to mark your problem as solved.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am reading the documentation provided by the answer.I will follow your advice after it done.

Comment: @孙世龙 Yes, the compiler error message. It will help other people to find this answer easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sloppy speaking, the ternary operator has some built-in conversion to a common type. You can read on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) how the type of the result is determined. The details are rather involved, so i'll put it in plain English: The result of `d < 0.00001 ? 0 : d;` is `double`.

In the no-conditional version one branch returns an `int` the other a `double`, hence the return type cannot be deduced.

Comment: This is a better link for implict conversion: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: And here is return type deduction: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Return_type_deduction

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Of course your links are good additions, but the one I wanted to include was about the conditional operator (not about implicit conversion). I just didnt know how to link the section directly